# Moving individual JSP to weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: jsp, weblogic

We're currently using Oracle OC4J server and we're planning to migrate our server to Weblogic 12.1.3. Entire migration of our applications is done. We've one outstanding question. Hoping someone could give an answer

Weblogic server is creating the application JSPs and class files dynamically in a runtime folder while deploying. i.e.; there is no way (at least we don't know at this point) to move an individual JSP to the weblogic server once the WAR has been deployed.

Is anyone worked with Weblogic 12.1.3 and do you know how an individual JSP can be moved to the deployed application folder without having to re-deploy the application?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deploy exploded archives as described in the section called Updating Static Files in a Deployed Application:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13702/redeploy.htm#DEPGD293